# At what stage does the user email change, on record save or on email verification?

Tags: email, administration, user-management

If I change a user's email address, I see that the email address does not update to the new email address when I save the record. Why is this? Is it because the user needs tio verify the new email address and there only the email address updates after the user has updated the email address or is it due to some other setting/reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for the change to take effect, the user has to confirm the change on the email that is sent to the new email address.